# How to test if pthread_setname_np() is available on my platform

Tags: pthreads, c-preprocessor

Some POSIX thread implementations define `pthread_setname_np()` to set a display name for a thread. However, this seems to be a nonstandard extension.

How can I test (via preprocessor directives) if the function is available on the platform I am building for, and skip the call if it is not?

Answer (score 0):

You can't test for a function existence with the preprocessor.

That kind of thing is exactly why people use build configuration tools like [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).  The idea is that you have you build environment define a preprocessor macro like `HAVE_PTHREAD_SETNAME_NP` only if such a function exists, then your code can just test for that macro with `#ifdef`.

Comment: That’s about as far as I got, I wanted to know if there’s e.g. some definition in the header file that gets set (by convention) if that function is available—but apparently there isn’t.

Comment: No, however you *could* perhaps test for particular C libraries and versions thereof (eg. `#if (__GLIBC__ > 2 || (__GLIBC__ == 2 && __GLIBC_MINOR >= 12)`.